# Converting the following Paypal curl command to axios?

Tags: curl, vue.js, paypal, httprequest, axios

How can I convert this paypal curl command to Axios?

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "client_id:secret" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I am using vueAxios in vue, hence the "*this.*".

```
this.axios.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    {'Accept': "application/json", 'Accept-Language': "en_US", 
    'XXXXXX': 'XXXXX', // my paypal client ID and client secret 
    'grant_type':'client_credentials'}
    )
    .then( response => {
        console.log("Response is: ", response);
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.log("Error is :", error);
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Error is : Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
    at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)
```

I've also tried this (which seems to be better but I'm still getting a 400 error):

```
 this.axios({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', 
    headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    auth: {
            username: '<XXXX My paypal client ID>',
            password: '<XXXX My paypal secret>'
    } ,
    data: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    },
})
.then(function(response) {console.log(response);})
.catch(function(response) {console.log(response);});
```

UPDATE – after some help form the comments I have tried the following code and the paypal has an issue CORS error ( i have installed a npm packages "cors" and the cors error persists (both locally and when deployed)).

This answers my question but, [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828320/paypal-access-control-allow-origin), it seems like Paypal doesn't allow requests directly from the browser.

```
this.axios({
    withCredentials: true,
    url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    data: { 'grant_type':'client_credentials' },
    auth: {
        username: 'XXXXXXXX',
        password: 'XXXXXXXX'
    }
})
```

Related documentation:

CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

VueAxios: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios

Paypal dev: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#make-your-first-call

Comment: No clue about axios, but I'm pretty sure that you mixed headers and the payload.

Comment: Yes. I don't know how to inform axios about what --header is, the --User credentials are and what's the --data... :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [axios GitHub docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```
this.axios({
  url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
  method: 'post',
  headers: { 
       'Accept': 'application/json', 
       'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
       'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
  },
  data: { 'grant_type':'client_credentials' },
  auth: {
    username: client_id,
    password: secret
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work 
I get this 415 error:
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token 415 (Unsupported Media Type)... so

I have added the content type Header to try and fix it: _'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'_ and it now returns a 400 error

Comment: Hmm. Could you try add `withCredentials: true` to `this.axios({})`?

Comment: I did and that threw a CORS error:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: ok. Not sure if your server allows cross origin request, but try add `{ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'Authorization' }` to the headers.

Comment: Also I am not sure `PayPal` API allows you to directly make request from the browser. If not, then you need to set up a server to make request on behalf of your frontend; that is, set up a server to make these requests and then send result to your frontend;

Answer (score 9):

this is a quite old thread. I've struggled too on this with node.js.
My solution hereafter. Hope this helps :

```
const res = await axios(
    {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
        data: 'grant_type=client_credentials', // => this is mandatory x-www-form-urlencoded. DO NOT USE json format for this
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',// => needed to handle data parameter
            'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
        },
        auth: {
            username: clientId,
            password: clientSecret
        },

    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data)); // => be sure to handle res.data, otherwise you will have a circular json error. The token you need is res.data.access_token.
```